# Running TypeScript in jsfiddle.net

Tags: typescript, jsfiddle

1. Select TypeScript in the JavaSCript pane
2. Open devtools console
3. Paste this simple snippet and run:

const y = ['abc'];
y.map((item) => item.toUpperCase());

What am I doing wrong around the arrow function that I am seeing "Unexpected identifier" errors?

Comment: I think there is  a problem with the embedded compiler your code gets transpiled to `y.map(function (item) item.toUpperCase(); );` yes with no `{ } `, it works fine on the playground: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20y%20%3D%20%5B'abc'%5D%3B%20y.map((item)%20%3D%3E%20item.toUpperCase())%3B

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your browser, there is nothing in that example that couldn't *in theory* work. For example, I'm running the latest version of Firefox and this example works as expected (treating the code as plain JavaScript).

```js
const y = ['abc'];
const result = y.map((item) => item.toUpperCase());
console.log(result);
```

However, not all browsers are equal at the time of writing, so you might want to down-level compile it all to something older... this version should work in all browsers, and it the output from the TypeScript compiler.

```js
var y = ['abc'];
var result = y.map(function (item) { return item.toUpperCase(); });
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The arrow functions code works just fine with "JavaScript" selected. But since TypeScript is a superset of JS, I would assume that the snippet worked with TS too. Assuming of course that there's a transpilation going on behind the hood.

Comment: The second code snippet was output by TypeScript - the code works fine. If you get `Unexpected identifier` it is more likely to be an error in a previous line of code. Are you sharing the whole example that generates that error?

Comment: Yes, this is the entire script that I had in jsfiddle. 3 lines of code.

Comment: It works in jsFiddle... it would come unstuck if you started to add type annotations or other features that haven't made it into a browser: https://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/7jmp7vuf/